# How to view all the filespec opened for a user in perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

Need some help :)

I am trying to write a script where given a username, I want to know all the files specs which are opened (user can see /check in / check out) for that user.

What I am looking for is something similar to

```
p4 groups -u <username>
```

which returns all the groups associated with that user. I want my script to do something similar like

```
myscript -u <username>
```

and it should return me the third level of file specs associated with them. Something like this:

```
//depot/file/path1/...
//depot/file/path2/...
//depot/file/path-n/...
```

where folder pathX will have some java or xml files under it.

Is there any perforce command or any other perforce api to do such kind of job ? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you possibly looking for 'p4 protects -u username'?

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/protects.html#1040665

Comment: Awesome. Thats exactly what I was looking for. That solves half of the purpose for my script. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `p4 protects` might require superuser privileges if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

`p4 opened -u USER` will show all files opened for edit by the specified user.

Comment: Actually the other answer was what i was looking for. When I said opened, I meant the permissions opened and not the checked out files. Thanks for replying though.